# Select Expired Records From MySQL Tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to show all those record which is Expired. but this show only the last one record which is expired.

The code contains pages. test.php and test1.php

test.php code is:

```
<?php


include("database/db.php"); 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


@$result = mysqli_query($link,"select * from advertiser,company_information,advertisement,ads_date
 WHERE Expiry_Date < CURDATE()");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $dateid = $row['Ads_date_id'];
$name=$row['Name'];
$cnic= $row['CNIC'];
$compname = $row['Company_Name'];
$adstitle = $row['Ads_Title'];
$startdate = $row['Starting_Date'];
$expiredate = $row['Expiry_Date'];



}
}
else
{

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("No Record Found");'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "SingleCustomer.php";';
echo '</script>';
}
mysqli_close($link);

?>
<?php
include("test1.php");
?>
```

test1.php code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Advertisement Information</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $name; ?></td>

<td> <?php echo $cnic; ?></td>

<td> <?php echo $compname; ?></td>

<td> <?php echo $adstitle; ?></td>

<td> <?php echo $startdate; ?></td>

<td> <?php echo $expiredate; ?></td>

<td> <?php echo $dateid; ?> </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

i have multiple tables in MYSQl.

```
1.advertiser
2.company_information
3.advertisement
4.ads_date
```

Advertiser:

```
CREATE TABLE `advertiser` (
  `Adv_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `F_Name` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `CNIC` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `Contact` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Monthly_fee` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Reg_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Adv_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2.Company_information:

```
CREATE TABLE `company_information` (
  `Company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Company_Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Company_Contact` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Company_Address` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

3.advertisement:

```
CREATE TABLE `advertisement` (
  `Ads_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Adv_id_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Ads_Title` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Ads_Description` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Ads_Image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ads_id`),
  KEY `Adv_id` (`Adv_id_id`),
  KEY `Company_id` (`Company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Adv_id` FOREIGN KEY (`Adv_id_id`) REFERENCES `advertiser` (`Adv_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `advertisement_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Company_id`) REFERENCES `company_information` (`Company_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

4.ads_date:

```
CREATE TABLE `ads_date` (
  `Ads_date_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Ads_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Starting_Date` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Expiry_Date` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ads_date_id`),
  KEY `Ads_id` (`Ads_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Ads_id` FOREIGN KEY (`Ads_id`) REFERENCES `advertisement` (`Ads_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You're only outputting the last result of the query in test1.php Your tables rows should be in the while loop.

Comment: then how to change the code??

Comment: See @Mureinik's answer below.

Comment: still not working. they are displaying all of the record from all of the four tables

Comment: You would have to perform `JOIN`'s in your query. You need to show your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you override your variables (`$name` etc.) in the `while` loop and then print them just once instead of printing them in every iteration of the loop. E.g.:

In test.php:

```
$htmlTable = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $htmlTable .= '<tr><td>' . row['Ads_date_id'] .
    . '</td><td>' . $row['Name']
    . '</td><td>' . $row['CNIC'];
    . '</td><td>' . $row['Company_Name'];
    . '</td><td>' . $row['Ads_Title'];
    . '</td><td>' . $row['Starting_Date'];
    . '</td><td>' . $row['Expiry_Date']
    . '</td></tr>';

}
```

And then in test1.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Advertisement Information</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
<?php echo $htmlTable; ?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
The second problem is that the query you're using is wrong. By just listing all the tables in the `from` clause with no join condition you're performing a Cartesian join (i.e., matching each record from each table with all the other records from the other tables). Instead, you should specify how these tables should be joined, preferably by using the modern explicit `join` syntax :

```
SELECT *  
FROM   advertisement a
JOIN   company_information ci ON ci.company_id = a.company_id
JOIN   advertiser ar ON ar.adv_id = a.adv_id
JOIN   ads_date ad ON ad.ads_id = a.ads_id
WHERE  expiry_date < CURDATE()
```

Comment: this is working great but the problem is i want to select only those records which is expired. this is selecting all the record from all of the four tables

Comment: @ImranKhan The query you were using was also wrong, sorry for missing that. See my edited answer.

Comment: Brother when i use for this two tables 1.ads_date and 2.advertisement. it's work perfect. but when i add the remaining two table it show error. the error is: Trying to get property of non object.

query work for two table is:
@$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * 
    FROM ads_date a
    JOIN advertisement ci ON ci.Ads_id = a.Ads_id
    WHERE Expiry_Date < CURDATE()");

Comment: is there a problem with relationship or anything else.?

Comment: Thanks dear you have done it. thanks again @Mureinik